Understanding the solution to a PDE exercise
We are asked to give, through the method of characteristics, a general solution to the PDE
$$-xu_x + yu_y = u + 2x$$
where $u$ is a function $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. The solution reads as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{-x}= \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{z+2x}$$
From
$$\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dy}{y} \implies \frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}{y} = 0\stackrel{*}{\implies} xy = C$$
and
$$\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dz}{z+2x}\implies\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{z+2x}{-x}\implies\frac{dz}{dx}+\frac{z}{x}=-2\stackrel{*}{\implies} z = -x+\frac{p(C)}{x}$$
Thus, the general solution is
$$u(x,y) = -\frac{p(xy)}{x}-x$$
for an arbitrary $C^1$ function $p$.

I struggle to understand the last implication of each lines, the ones marked $(*)$. In particular, where does the function $p$ come from? Why is $xy$ given as an argument to $p$? How does it help solve the PDE?

Interesting. Somehow they're making a deduction 1 - because the sum of functions of different variables is a constant like $F(x)+G(y)=C$ therefore so and so instead of just integrating directly from the equations prior right? 2 - and then it's not quite the same as the 1st case still the same principle they could just integrate the $\frac{dz}{dx}$ part, but instead they want to do $F(\cdot)+G(\cdot)=K$ right?

@BCLC What would $F$ and $G$ be in this example? All I can see is that $d(xy) = y(dx)+x(dy) = xy$.

For 1 I guess $F(x)=\frac{dx}{x}$ and $G(y)=\frac{dy}{y}$. I remember many rules in ... ah I think partial integration or something when you equate a function $H$ of $x$ and then a function $J$ of $y$ then that means they're equal to a constant. Like $H(x)=J(y)$ (for all x and y in their common domain or whatever) implies $C=H(x)=J(y)$. For 2 - not sure. apparently there's some formula like $\frac{dz}{dx} + \frac z x = K$ then the solution is $z = $ ? But anyway it looks like just some kinda shortcut based on integrating from the previous equations.

3 - as to how $p$ is a function of $C$ yeah good question. maybe it comes from the 3rd equation $\frac{dy}y = \frac{dz}{z+2x}$  combined with $xy=C$ ?
